# Some features of Activity stops working onRestart()

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-drawer

I have created a `navigation drawer` in my application, Its working fine, but when i open another activity and go back to previous activity, the button of navigation drawer stops working, Although `navigation drawer` is still there. If i slide from left to right it opens the drawer, but when i click on `Hamburger` icon, it just doesn't do anything.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_navigation);

        ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.base_layout);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(getLayoutRes(), content, true);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_main);
        headerLayout= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.header_layout);
        btnOpenDrawer= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_openDrawer);
        homeLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_layout);



        btnOpenDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });
```

Kindly guide me that what i need to add in `onRestart()`. Do i need to write all this code in `onRestart()` as well?

Comment: Can you post your full class please

Comment: Everything you need including code is in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: try adding a `ActionBarDrawerToggle`